# Cordova error - "npm does not support Node.js v0.12.9"

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, npm, visual-studio-cordova

When I build my Cordova project in Visual Studio, it gives me an error "npm does not support Node.js v0.12.9" even though I have v6.10.3 installed. I tried the latest versions of npm, both x86 & x64.

It used to work, not sure what broke it.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you solve it yet?

Comment: try going through this:  http://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-update-nodejs-andor-npm-latest-version/

Comment: @MichaelWinther Hi Michael, can you try the suggestion i mentioned in the comments of wezten's answer?

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the build output again, and noticed that there were other errors too, although I can't remember what they were. It could be I had to increase the build output verbosity using Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run.

Looking at the xml in the .jsproj to see what the build process was doing, showed that it was running the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-t‌​ac\install.js` script. I put in console.log statements to see exactly what was happening, and somewhere along the way my error disappeared, not sure how.

So I can't give a precise answer, but this should help other users to debug their issues.

Comment: have you made an entry in external web tools section in VS to force the VS to use specific version as mentioned here - https://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/ This should probably resolve your issue.

Comment: did you had a look at the link by any chance?

Comment: @Gandhi I cannot reproduce the issue anymore, as I wrote in my answer that the error disappeared. Try asking Michael Winther who is offering the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Somehow checking the "Use globally installed Cordova version" in config.xml did the trick for me.